# New Text File Based On Blank Line

Tags: regex, linux

I have a text file that looks like:

```
6789 Here is a bunch of text

4565 More text......................................................
.....etc
```

I need to pull out the first word (numbers) and create a new file contain all of the following text making the first word its file name until a blank line and then repeat creating many text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the awk line can do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} {fn=$1;gsub(/^[0-9]+\s/,"");print $0 > (fn".txt")}' yourFile
```

**test**:

```
kent$  l 
total 0
(no file in current dir)

kent$  echo "6789 Here is a bunch of text

4565 More text......................................................
.....etc"|awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} {fn=$1;gsub(/^[0-9]+\s/,"");print $0 > (fn".txt")}'

kent$  ls
4565.txt  6789.txt

and, the contents are:

kent$  head *.txt
==> 4565.txt <==
More text......................................................
.....etc

==> 6789.txt <==
Here is a bunch of text
```

Answer (score 0):

[`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) and Split will do (part of) the job:

```
$ awk '{print $1} < foo | split -p '^$'
```

If you really need to rename each file according to the number at the beginning of the file, then you will probably want to solve this problem in perl or python.